# the same tr translate failed on some of machine

Tags: bash, zsh, solaris

I use the following code and failed.

```
$ echo $TERM
xtermc
$ v=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin ; echo $v | tr ':' '\n'
/binn/usr/binn/usr/local/bin
```

It seems skip my '/'. I don't know how to solve this.
My shell is zsh. I've changed to bash, but still failed.

But, on another machine, it works. and the result is

```
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

I found there are three tr

```
/usr/local/bin/tr (GNU coreutils) 6.4
/usr/ucb/tr unkown version size 9916 bytes
/bin/tr size 19400 Usage: /bin/tr [ -cds ] [ String1 [ String2 ] ]
```

Comment: Are both machines running Solaris? Could you post the output of `which tr` and `tr --version` on both machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by different tr and different PATH setup.

```
works: /usr/local/bin/tr (GNU coreutils) 6.4
failed: /usr/ucb/tr unkown version size 9916 bytes
works: /bin/tr size 19400 Usage: /bin/tr [ -cds ] [ String1 [ String2 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using zsh, you can use this approach and won't rely on any external command anymore:

```
$ v=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin; print -l ${(s.:.)v}
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

How it works:

- the parameter expansion flag `(s.:.)` splits the parameter `$v` at colons (see `man zshexpn`)
- `print -l` prints every following argument on a single line

If you rely an the *newline character*, use

```
$ print ${v//:/\\n}
```

where `//from/to` does a global (two beginning slashes) search & replace.